# Go Lang - Interfaces and arrays

Tags: arrays, interface, go

I have a variable that i think is of type "[]interface {}"

1. How do i detect it
2. Convert to array  ?

Here's the code:

```
var s string
switch value1 := value1.(type) {
case int:
    s = strconv.Itoa(value1)
case float64:
    s = strconv.FormatFloat(value1, 'f', 0, 64)
//case array:
    //fmt.Printf("array")
default :
    fmt.Printf("\nvalue=v+%",value1)
}
```

And the output is:

```
value=v+%!(NOVERB)%!(EXTRA []interface {}=
```

Comment: could you please format the code properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select for a slice in a type switch the same as other types.  For example:

```
switch v := value1.(type) {
case []interface{}:
    for _, element := range v {
        fmt.Println(element)
    }
}
```

You can play with this example here: http://play.golang.org/p/4z9eejp4BL